# How to set up different web.config for different publication profiles in Visual Studio 2015 community?

Tags: visual-studio, web-config, publishing

How to set up diferent web.config for different publication profiles in Visual Studio 2015 community?

All manuals say that you should to click on web.config and choose "add config transform" in menu. But i have not this string in menu.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXb90.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably excluded from the community edition. It is available in Professional